# Is there a way to pass data between views in ios xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I am new to iOS development. I have an application with three different tabs. Each of the tab views contains 3 same buttons. and each button points to another tableview. Is there a way to find out which tab view the button was clicked in.

So there are three buttons in three views. Each single button in every view points to one single other view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A View (or a ViewController) is just a C# class.  You can can pass data to it like you would any C# class.  Pass an argument in the constructor, or set a public property, or call a public setter method.

In your specific case, you can also check the SelectedIndex property of your UITabBarController to find out which tab is active when a button is clicked.